# Rewrite struct without typedef

Tags: c, struct

I have this struct :

```
typedef struct std_fifo{
    char* name;
    struct std_fifo* next;
}std_fifo, *fifo;
```

And the two following methods :

```
char* remove(fifo* f){
    if((*f)==NULL)
        return NULL;
    char* tmp=(*f)->name;
    fifo tmpFifo= *f;
    *f=(*f)->next;
    free(tmpFifo);
    return tmp;
}

fifo add(fifo f,char* new){
    if(f==NULL){
        fifo newFifo=malloc(sizeof(std_fifo));

        newFifo->name=malloc(strlen(new)+1);

        strcpy(newFifo->name,new);
        newFifo->next=NULL;
        return newFifo;
    }
    f->next=add(f->next,new);
    return f;
}
```

I would like to rewrite this, but without the typedef fifo*. I mean with this struc :

```
struct Fifo{
    char* name;
    struct Fifo* next;
};
```

My question may seem ridiculous but I have difficulities with struct and typedef, so it would be really nice if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

I did something like that :

```
char* remove(struct Fifo* fifo){
    if(fifo == NULL)
        return NULL;
    char* name = fifo->name;
    fifo = fifo->next;
    return name;
}
```

Is it correct ?

Comment: Why is `add` returning a Fifo object?

Comment: it's returning a Fifo because I need the uptaded Fifo later in my prgram

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `struct Fifo` *everywhere*. The `struct` token is part of its name.

For example:

```
char* remove(struct Fifo* f) {
```

Comment: I have edit my post. Can you tell me if it is correct ? In the first add method, there is `*f=(*f)->next;` for example. And without the typedef, i did `fifo = fifo->next;`. Is it ok ?

Comment: No the remove method is not correct. You have replaced a pointer to a pointer to a struct with a pointer to a struct.   Modifying the latter will not affect the caller's list.

Comment: @LucasPierrat Don't edit your question with the answer -_-

Comment: Small modification to what Jonathon said.  Everywhere you had a `fifo` typedef, you need to replace it with `struct Fifo*`.

Comment: @AShelly So what should I do to have a pointer to a pointer to a struct ?

Comment: @LucasPierrat  `struct Fifo **`

Comment: @CareyGregory I am really sorry but I don't think I understant well.. I have big difficulties with pointers and structs.. Could you please rewrite me the two methods ?

Comment: @LucasPierrat It's a simple text substitution. Everywhere you see `std_fifo` or `fifo` in your code, just replace it with `struct fifo`. Learning how to use pointers is a separate question.

Comment: Use a struct exactly as you would use any basic type. A pointer to a struct is just like any other pointer.

Comment: @CareyGregory, that's not quite right.  the original `fifo` becomes a `struct Fifo *`.  The * is important.

Comment: @AShelly Yes, true, I commented in haste. Only `std_fifo` becomes `struct fifo`. `fifo` becomes `struct fifo *`.

Answer (score 0):

`struct` defines a NOT trivial type (int, char, etc are trivial types), containing one or more fields. `typedef`defines an alias, a short version of a long definition. Despite of the world being full of trivial typedefs, such use is not advised; better reserve it for not trivial, long definitions.

For example, let's define a pointer to an unsigned int, and then a var of that type:

```
typedef unsigned int* uip;
uip myVar; //myVar is a pointer to an unsigned int
```

Using a `typedef struct` combination may be possible (?). Anyhow is not needed because struct is another word used for definintions.

```
struct myType
{
    int val;
    char* array;
/*...*/
}
myType myStruct; //myStruct is of type myType
```

Comment: Your first sentence is an overstatement. The world is full of typedefs for 'trivial' types. For example, the Windows header files are full of them.

Comment: @CareyGregory Windows is well known for its mmmhh... obfuscated way. Anyhow a typedef is also used as a way of defining special types for a special case, so the compiler would assert if types don't match. This goes beyond what the OP needs to know by now.

Comment: I don't disagree that using typedefs to define simple types is bad practice, but it's both perfectly valid C and a common practice, so I think your first sentence makes your answer wrong. Just reword it to say it's not advised or not a best practice.

Comment: @CareyGregory. Thanks for your sugestion. Done.